# Whois script bash

Tags: linux, bash, whois

I have made `whois` script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store the list of domains in an array
while read domain
do
  # Output the header
  echo "Domain,Registrar,Creation Date,Expiration Date"

  # Perform a WHOIS lookup for each domain
  whois_output=$(whois "$domain")

  # Extract the relevant information from the WHOIS output
  registrar=$(echo "$whois_output" | grep "Registrar:" | awk '{print $2}')
  creation_date=$(echo "$whois_output" | grep "Creation Date:" | awk '{print $3}')
  expiration_date=$(echo "$whois_output" | grep "Expiration Date:" | awk '{print $3}')

  # Output the information in a row
  echo "$domain,$registrar,$creation_date,$expiration_date" >> domain_info.csv
done < domains.csv
```

The output is coming in vertical way:

```
Facebook.com
Creation date
Update date


And I want data in horizontal way like: 


Facebook.com,creation date , update date
```

[this is the output I want &](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytFcT.png) 
[this the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJsS3.png)

Comment: As a general note, `echo | grep | awk` is needless, because everything `grep` can do `awk` can do too: You can use `registrar=$(echo "$whois_output" | awk '/Registrar:/ {print $2}')` to do both the filtering and the column selection at once.

Comment: Anyhow -- what does `bash -x yourscript` say it's assigning to the `domain`, `registrar`, &c variables? There _shouldn't_ be newlines in their contents, but if there were it would explain the bug.

Comment: Hi thanks, this is  an example i have made many scripts of whois if i talk about python-whois representation of output is what i needed but sadly python -whois unable to retrieve all the information  and if i talk about bash output information is coming in vertical way like Facebook.com under its creation date i want in horizontal way .

Comment: Please answer the question about the output of running your script with trace logging (as done with `bash -x`).

Comment: `whois stackoverflow.com | grep Registrar: | awk '{print $2}'`; `whois facebook.com | grep Registrar: | awk '{print $2}'`. Hmmm...

Comment: Try deleting `domain_info.csv` and run it again.

Comment: `...| awk '-F:' '{print $2}'` may work better. Also msg to O.P. Make an `awk` script that captures all variables required and uses `printf("%s,%s,%s\n", Reg, CreDt, UpDt)`. Good luck.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : ++ grep 'Expiration Date:'
    https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en.'
++ awk '{print $3}'
+ expiration_date=Expiration
+ echo 'facebook.com,RegistrarSafe,
RegistrarSafe,,1997-03-29T05:00:00Z
1997-03-29T05:00:00Z,Expiration'
+ read domain

Comment: @jhnc hi , I have tried this but the output which is saving in csv is in vertical way .I need in sequence i .e in horizontal way

Comment: @konsolebox hi nothing change data coming in vertical way only

Comment: @shellter hi its just an example I want output in csv in horizontal way .

Comment: `echo 'facebook.com,RegistrarSafe, RegistrarSafe,,1997-03-29T05:00:00Z 1997-03-29T05:00:00Z,Expiration'` _does_ write exactly one line "in a horizontal way" like you ask for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sir when i save output in csv it will shows as vertical . apart from this i cannot share CSV results here other wise it will clearly shows my  problem

Comment: "Shows as vertical" in what software? Are you viewing your CSV with a text editor or with something like a spreadsheet?

Comment: (And why do you mean you can't share the result here? You can insert the text of the CSV file into the question the same way your code is inserted)

Comment: You have misunderstood my comment. Your variables like `registrar` can be set to multiple newline-delimited values. I showed the examples of stackoverflow and facebook which both give multiple values for `registrar`. When you later do `echo "...$registratar..."` you will find newlines inserted for such values.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hi I have attached the csv you can check above I hope you'll get it.

Comment: That's not a CSV, that's an Excel screenshot. Please provide **the actual CSV** -- and, ideally, the `bash -x yourscript` trace of the execution that generated it. I _suspect_ that the problem is what jhnc's answer suggests, which is also what I suggested in an earlier comment.

Comment: (Note that if in `echo 'facebook.com,RegistrarSafe, RegistrarSafe,,1997-03-29T05:00:00Z 1997-03-29T05:00:00Z,Expiration'` what _looks_ like a space is actually a newline, that would explain your problem; spaces and newlines looking the same in a comment is part of why it's bad practice to paste code into comments -- it should instead be edited into the question itself to not corrupt the formatting)

Comment: The other thing you can do is `echo "${registrar%%$'\n'*}"` to emit only the first line of the registrar variable.

Comment: Or use `registrar=$(echo "$whois_output" | awk '/Registrar/ {print $2; exit}')` -- the `exit` will make `awk` print only one line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks there one more question if I run command whois facebook.com  | grep -i "Admin Organization: "| cut -d ":" -f2 . output is like : Meta Platforms, Inc.
you can see comma after platforms this comma makes another column in csv is there any way to combine so that Meta Platform Inc comes under single column?

Comment: Ideally, use a real CSV generation library instead of hacking something up with bash in the first place. Something like the Python CSV module will add quotes around the whole string so the comma isn't treated as a separator. You can of course add quotes in your bash too, but then you need to double up any quotes in the data so they aren't treated as syntax on the parsing end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the vertical to horizontal conversion, I think the simplest fix is to simply remove the newlines which can be done by piping to `tr` command:

```
# Output the information in a row
echo "$domain,$registrar,$creation_date,$expiration_date" | tr -d '\n' >> domain_info.csv
```

Comment: yeah it works good for one domain present in csv if mulitples domains present in csv all domains are in single line

Comment: @ROHAN, so add a `printf '\n'` on a separate line after the echo that _doesn't_ go through the `tr -d`

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed that `whois_output` will contain something after the `whois` call and that `registrar`, `creation_date` and `expiration_date` will all end up with precisely one value each.

These assumptions are incorrect.

For example, the output of `whois facebook.com | grep Registrar:` (when I run it here) is:

```
   Registrar: RegistrarSafe, LLC
Registrar: RegistrarSafe, LLC
```

so when you run your `awk '{print $2}'` command, the variable `registrar` contains:

```
RegistrarSafe,
RegistrarSafe,
```

(There is an embedded newline.).

Later when you do `echo "$domain,$registrar,[...]"` you will get:

```
facebook.com,RegistrarSafe,
RegistrarSafe,,[...]
```

The fix to your problem is to ensure precisely one value is assigned to each of your variables, and that they do not contain embedded newlines.

For valid csv output, you should probably also quote any value that contains commas.